# How to perform a segue between a separated UITableViewCell and another view

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitableview, tableview

Here's what I have :

A Storyboard with A UIViewController that contains a `UITableView`. Next to it, I have a `UITabBarController` that handles 5 other views.

I defined a "generic" segue between the `ViewController` and the `TabBarController`, in order to be able to call it after.

Here's a subview of my storyboard :

[image]

For my UITableView, I've created two custom `UITableViewCells` in separated .xib files.

I don't really know how to tell my application to `performSegueWithIdentifier:` when I click on one of the cells, as I can't really set the segue in IB directly between the cell and the destination view.

Could anyone give me some tips about how to do it properly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your implementation of `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` (or similar method), you can tell the view controller to use the generic segue you created earlier, by calling `-[UIViewController performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:]`. You can set the identifier on the segue in your storyboard.

For the sender, you can pass the UITableViewCell instance, or any other object you want to pass. This will get used when the view controller calls your `prepareForSegue:sender:` method, and is a great way of determining what the user tapped to cause the segue. Then you can prepare the next view controller using this sender/context.

Comment: Which sender should I pass to this method then ?

Comment: You can use the UITableViewCell instance, or any other object you want to pass. This will get used when the view controller calls your `prepareForSegue:sender:` method, and is a great way of determining what the user tapped to cause the segue.

Comment: You need to implement UITableViewDelegate. Then you will receive `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` when the user taps that cell.